# SELECT two tables and display the output

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to output two tables and display it to my form
but the problem is when i Output second tables i got an error..

This is my first tables and it works fine.

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];
$tjbvqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`,`jobcode`,`cdate`,`start`,`end`,`group`,`projecttitle`,`location`,`dealer` FROM table_joborder WHERE id = ?");
$tjbvqry->bind_param('i', $id);
$tjbvqry->execute();
$tjbvqry->bind_result($id,$jcode,$cdate,$start,$end,$group,$projecttitle,$location,$dealer);

if(!$tjbvqry->fetch()){

  throw new Exception("Error Processing Request". $id , 404);

}

//Fetching all data from database//
while ($row = $tjbvqry->fetch()){

  $id           = $row['id'];
  $jcode        = $row['jobcode'];
  $cdate        = $row['cdate'];
  $start        = $row['start'];
  $end          = $row['end'];
  $group        = $row['group'];
  $projecttitle = $row['projecttitle'];
  $location     = $row['location'];
  $dealer       = $row['dealer'];
}
```

but when I select the second tables and output them
I Got an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error Processing Request18'

This is my second tables

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
$tjcqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
                                   requisition,
                                   status,
                                   estimatedstart,
                                   estimatedcomplete,
                                   timestarted,
                                   timeend,
                                   contractor,
                                   details,
                                   description,
                                   completed,
                                   verified,
                                   leader,
                                   members FROM table_jobordercompleted WHERE id = ?");
$tjcqry->bind_param('i', $id);
$tjcqry->execute();
$tjcqry->bind_result($requisition,$status,$estart,$ecomplete,$tstarted,
                         $timeend,$contractor,$details,$description,$completed,$verified,$leader,$member);
if(!$tjcqry->fetch()){

  throw new Exception("Error Processing Request" . $id  , 404);

}

while ($row  = $tjcqry->fetch()){


  $requisition    = $row['requisition'];
  $status         = $row['status'];
  $estart         = $row['estimatedstart'];
  $ecomplete      = $row['estimatedcomplete'];
  $tstarted       = $row['timestarted'];
  $timeend        = $row['timeend'];
  $contractor     = $row['contractor'];
  $details        = $row['details'];
  $description    = $row['description'];
  $completed      = $row['completed'];
  $verified       = $row['verified'];
  $leader         = $row['leader'];
  $member         = $row['members'];


}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no typos?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that's all are correct
but I don't know what is the error?

Comment: what happens when you run the sql query from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Hi @Orlo
How to check in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @user3367242 your error indicates that the id is 18 so try running `SELECT requisition,status,estimatedstart,estimatedcomplete,timestarted,timeend,contractor,details,description,completed,verified,leader,members  FROM table_jobordercompleted WHERE id='18'`

Comment: I don't think anything's wrong with the id 18 in particular, but you should definitely check what happens in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hi guys
Thanks
the id now is fixed
but 
when i retrieved all from table_jobordercompleted
nothing retrieve.
help me please.